# Understanding the Lie Algebra of left-invariant vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

I’m very new to differential geometry and I am currently studying Lie Groups and now I have some trouble understanding the Lie Algebra of left-invariant vector fields over $G$, where $G$ is a Lie group.

Let’s start stating what I think I got right:

Given a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ manifold $M$, $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$ is the  set of all functions $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ s.t. for all charts $\varphi:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$, the map $f\circ\varphi^{-1}$ is infinitely differentiable.

A smooth vector field on a manifold $M$ is a linear function $X:\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)\to\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$ s.t. $X$ is a derivation, i.e., $\forall f,g\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$ it holds that $X(fg)=fX(g)+X(f)g$. The set of all such functions $X$, is denoted by $\mathfrak{X}(M)$.
If we equip $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ with the commutator $[X,Y] = X\circ Y - Y\circ X$ we obtain a Lie Algebra.

First of all I want to ask you if what I stated so far is correct, in order to proceed with the main question.

Given a Lie group $G$, we define the following Lie Subalgebra of $\mathfrak{X}(M)$, called the Lie algebra of left-invariant vector fields over $G$:

$\operatorname{Lie}(G):=\{X\in\mathfrak{X}(G) : \forall g\in G, \,\,\,d(L_g)X=X\}$

where $L_g:G\to G$ associate to each $g'\in G$ $L_g(g')=gg'$.
Now I have some trouble understanding the condition $d(L_g)X=X$. From what I thought, given a function $f:G\to \mathbb{R}$ the differential of $f$ gives the following: $df(X)=X(f)$. But now we are differentiating $L_g$ which is not a real valued function, so I don’t understand the meaning of the condition $d(L_g)X=X$. Since what I wrote about the differential can’t hold, what does $d(L_g)$ mean?

I know this might be a really naive question, but I’m new to these topics. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you, guys.

Comment: Have you heard about the differential of a smooth map $f:M\to N$ between two smooth manifolds? The differential of a smooth function $M\to\mathbf R$ is a special case.

Comment: I think so, but it always involve some point. Given two smooth manifolds $M$,$N$, a smooth map $f$ between those two manifolds and a point $x\in M$ I think it should be a map between $T_x M$ and $T_{f(x)} N$. Is that right? But since here there are no point involved I don't see a way to utilize this definition of differential.

Comment: The linear maps $df_x$ at each point $x$ of $M$ can be packaged together to be a single smooth map between the tangent bundles,  $df:TM\to TN$. That is what you should be thinking about.

Comment: Could you please unfold this definition of $df$ you gave? I don't think I heard of that one

Comment: The differential of a smooth map between manifolds, as a smooth map between their tangent bundles, should be in nearly any book on smooth manifolds (Lee, Tu, Warner,…).

Comment: I recommend to add some juicy meat to those dry definitions by explicitly calculating left invariant vector fields of a few popular Lie group examples, say, Heisenberg group or $SU(2)\,.$ A bit simpler (potentially boring) could even be the [affine group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group#Matrix_representation).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f:M\to N$ is a smooth map between smooth manifolds. This gives us the tangent map between tangent bundles $Tf:TM\to TN$. At a fiberwise level this restricts, for each $x\in M$, to a map $Tf_x:T_xM\to T_{f(x)}N$. The notation is far from standardizes; although I prefer $Tf$ and $Tf_x$ (or $T_xf$), other notations include $df$ and $df_x$ (or $d_xf$ or $df(x)$), or $Df$ and $Df_x$ (or $D_xf$ or $Df(x)$), or $\phi_*$ and $\phi_{*,x}$ etc. Basically, anything which reminds you of a derivative. Names for this include ‘tangent map’ (which is the one I prefer), or ‘differential’, or ‘pushforward’.

Once we have this notion, given any vector field $X$ (recall, one way of defining this is as a smooth map $X:M\to TM$ such that $\pi_M\circ X=\text{id}_M$, i.e a section of the tangent bundle), if we have a **diffeomorphism** $f:M\to N$, then we can define a new vector field $f_*X$ on $N$, called the *pushforward of $X$ by/under/via $f$*. The definition is $f_*X:= Tf\circ X\circ f^{-1}$ (draw a commutative diagram so you know where everything is… this is a ‘left-up-right’ movement of the arrows). If you write this out pointwise, then for each $y\in N$, we are assigning the vector
\begin{align}
(f_*X)_y:=Tf_{f^{-1}(y)}\left(X_{f^{-1}(y)}\right)\in T_yN,
\end{align}
or equivalently (since $f$ is a diffeomorphism), for each $x\in M$, $(f_*Y)_{f(x)}=Tf_x\left(X_x\right)\in T_{f(x)}N$.

Just extra FYI: given a diffeomorphism $f:M\to N$ and a smooth vector field $Y$ on $N$, we can define a vector field $f^*Y$ on $M$, called the *pullback of $Y$ under $f$*,
\begin{align}
f^*Y:=(f^{-1})_*Y=T(f^{-1})\circ Y\circ f=(Tf)^{-1}\circ Y\circ f.
\end{align}

---

The condition for left-invariance of a vector field $X$ on a Lie group $G$ is then that for each $g\in G$, we require $(L_g)_*X=X$. It is equivalent to say that for all $g\in G$, $(L_g)^*X=X$.

For right-invariance, simply replace $L_g$ with $R_g$, the right-multiplication by $g$.

Comment: Oh, turns out I once answered a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3326316/568204).

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot. Let me just ask something to confirm I got it right. The tangent bundle of $M$ is $TM=\{(x,y) : x\in M, y\in T_xM\}$, given a smooth map $f:M\to N$, we define $Tf: TM\to TN$ such that $\pi_N\circ TF=f\circ\pi_M$. Now given your definitions of vector fields and of pushforward, where $L_g$ plays the role of the diffeomorphism $f$ between G and itself, the condition $(L_g)_*X=X$ is equal to require that $TL_g\circ X\circ L_g^{-1} = X$. Where $TL_g:TG\to TG$ is the map such that $\pi_G\circ TL_g=L_g\circ\pi_G$.

Comment: @cento18 correct.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother almost  a week later but I have a very related question. We said above that $(L_g)_*$ is an application that takes a vector field $X:G\to TG$ and gives as output a vector field of the same kind: $Y:G\to TG$. In order to prove that $Lie(G)$ is a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{X}(G)$ (both defined as in the main question), I have to prove that $(L_g)_*[X,Y]=[(L_g)_*X,(L_g)_*Y]$, so that by invariance we get $(L_g)_*[X,Y]=[X,Y]$.

Comment: My problem is that the Lie Bracket is defined as the commutator and uses the definition of vector fields as derivations on $C^{\infty}(G)$, while $(L_g)_*$ uses the defintion of vector fields as maps from $G$ to $TG$. So when trying to prove $(L_g)_*[X,Y]=[(L_g)_*X,(L_g)_*Y]$ the two different definitions of vector field are involved. Is there a way to define the Lie Bracket on $\mathfrak{X}(G)$ according to the latter definition of vector field (maps $G\to TG$)? Otherwise, how do I prove $(L_g)_*[X,Y]=[(L_g)_*X,(L_g)_*Y]$?

Comment: @cento18 the definition of a vector field $X$ on a smooth manifold $M$ as I have given it here (i.e a smooth section of the tangent bundle, $X:M\to TM$ such that $\pi\circ X=\text{id}_M$) is equivalent to being a derivation of $C^{\infty}(M)$, $\tilde{X}:C^{\infty}(M)\to C^{\infty}(M)$. This equivalence is proven in any good textbook. Next, if you truly understood the idea of pushforward you should be able to reformulate the definition using derivations as well.

Comment: Suppose $\phi:M\to N$ is a diffeomorphism and $Y:C^{\infty}(N)\to C^{\infty}(N)$ is a derivation. I somehow want to define a derivation on $C^{\infty}(M)$. Given a function $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$, I need to produce another function on $M$. The obvious way is to first define a function on $N$, namely $f\circ\phi^{-1}$. Then, I can apply $Y$ to this function; this gives me a new function on $N$, $Y(f\circ\phi^{-1})$. If I want to convert this into a function on $M$, then I simply compose: $[Y(f\circ\phi^{-1})]\circ \phi$. So, $(\phi^*Y)(f):=[Y(f\circ\phi^{-1})]\circ\phi$.

Comment: Anyway, the stuff regarding Lie brackets and push forwards you’re asking are basic things, and have nothing special to do with Lie groups. I suggest reading a good differential geometry text, for example Lee’s *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, and look for the chapter on vector fields, flows, Lie brackets etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know it's basic stuff, but this is my very first differential geometry course and unfortunately we were not given enough basic notions to take the exam. Will definetly look into that book! Thank u again :)

Comment: oh and I’m using ‘basic’ in a vauge sense btw. I meant ‘basic’ as in ‘covered usually in a first course’, not that it’s easy. But once you get the hang of it, it gets easier. One piece of advice is to not memorize the formulas because then you’ll get stuck with all sorts of ‘type’ issues, eg $M\to TM$ vs $C^{\infty}(M)$ issue. Rather think of the underlying idea. For the pullback/pushforward, the idea is ‘I have something defined on one space, and a map between spaces, so how can I ‘create’ an object on the other space’. With this idea in mind, both definitions are almost ‘forced’ upon you :)